# Modifying browser plugin list from cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, browser-plugin

I am trying list and modify the browser's [navigator.plugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.plugins) from a Cocoa application on OS X. I did not find a way to list the plugin list installed on OS X. On Windows I am able to check the registry and modify it.
Any leads are greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is your goal? Installing & registering a plugin?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche I want to create a plugin, I will look at the docs on that. But my main requirement is identifying if my desktop app is installed and launching it so making a small hack by adding a dummy item to the list of plugins from the desktop app(Cocoa app) so that when a user opens a my web application it will identify that this guy has installed my desktop app and I can launch that.

Comment: As there is no registry you could modify here, you could put a minimal dummy plugin in the paths bdash mentions. But that still seems like a rather crude hack, there should be some better solution.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche I am hoping for one better solution. But javascript running in the browser will not be able to access anything outside(system information).

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers on OS X enumerate the Internet plug-ins in several locations on disk. Plug-ins shared between browsers are found at `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` and `~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins`, while application-specific Internet plug-ins typically reside inside `[[NSBundle mainBundle] builtInPlugInsPath]`. The only way to modify the list of Internet plug-ins that a browser sees is to move the plug-in bundles out of the directories that comprise the search path.